# How to use ternary operator to change value of ng-model in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator, ng-class

I have one text field and one checkbox. If checkbox is true I want value from address field to become after the checkbox, if false the field should be empty. I tried ternary operator with ng-class and many more, but no luck. What would be the best and working solution for that?

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanurmi/3Lh1y34v/)

```
<form name="form" ng-app>
<div class="form-group form-group-lg required">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Address:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10" ">
        <input type="text " name="address " class="form-control " ng-model="address " ng-minlength="4 " placeholder="Address " required>
     </div>

</div>   
<div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Return Address</label>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
               <!--condition ? first_expression : second_expression; -->
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isReturnAddress" ng-change="">
            </span><!--condition ? first_expression : second_expression; -->
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="address">
         </div>
 {{isReturnAddress}}
    </div>
</div> 
<button type="submit " class="btn btn-primary btn-large " ng-click="submitted=true ">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You can do some inline stuff, but why not just have a method on the controller to handle the logic for you? And then call {{putTextIWantHere()}}

Comment: I am trying to learn AngularJS at the same time, but maybe I just handle it inside the controller. I was thinking that this will be easy case, but I recognised that it wasn't :)

Comment: Oh, if you are brand new, then you are probably looking for ng-if, or ng-show. I had assumed you were talking about not using those.

Comment: Those are ok as well. I implemented it to controller and it is working fine, but if you have something working in mind, I am happy to hear it, I mean without adding anything to controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use two input elements in this case. Like

```
<input ng-if="isReturnAddress" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="address">
<input ng-if="!isReturnAddress" type="text" class="form-control">
```

and in your controller, please check

```
if($scope.isReturnAddress){
  var address = $scope.address;
}
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0gky3bn/1/) here

Comment: it was so easy :) Thanks. Is it even possible with ternary? Maybe, but it is just waste of time trying to solve it. BTW, is it possible to combine ng-models if I want to show address, city, zip etc without using controller?

Comment: There is some error in that ternary operation version, but I am happy with first version. I have to use controller version anyway, because I want to show the whole address with city, country and zip and they are in different model. Thank you very much!